# Why does Alamofire use 30 seconds for the timeout expectations on Unit Tests?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, alamofire

I'm investigating how `Alamofire` executes Unit Tests for `NSOperation`s. This is the base test class used by other tests. Any idea why does it use `30` seconds for the `timeout` for the expectation?

```
import Alamofire
import Foundation
import XCTest

class BaseTestCase: XCTestCase {
    let timeout: NSTimeInterval = 30.0

    func URLForResource(fileName: String, withExtension: String) -> NSURL {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: BaseTestCase.self)
        return bundle.URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: withExtension)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use 30 seconds as our standard timeout. Now that's way longer than you should ever need when running locally, but things always run slower on a CI environment such as Travis-CI. Therefore, we raised the default timeout to give the slower machines more time to process the tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I asked the question since I am trying to unit test a custom`NSOperation` in Circle CI but I have a timeout issue.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd first just bump up the timeout and see where that gets you.

Comment: Thanks. So, the problem could be due to lower resources in Circle CI (compared to local ones).

Comment: Yes, that is most commonly the issue. The distributed environments run much differently than the local test suite.